# dynamic UITableViewCell height

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to get my cell to dynamicly change height depending on how much text is in the cell.. Currently I have the words wrapping.. but as soon as there is to much content for the cell (if it goes to a 3rd line) you cannot see anything past the 2nd line.

This is what I have so far.. hopefully someone can see if I am missing something or doing something wrong... any help would be appreciated.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UILabel *label = nil;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
        [label setTag:1];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
    }

     //    //Display cells with data that has been sorted from startSortingTheArray
NSArray *keys = [self.letterDictionary objectForKey:[self.sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size = [key sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

if (!label)
    label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

[label setText:key];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];






//Applise current key value to cell text label
//cell.textLabel.text = key;
return cell;
}

//Cell size for word wrapping.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    //Display cells with data that has been sorted from startSortingTheArray
    NSArray *keys = [self.letterDictionary objectForKey:[self.sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@", key);

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [key sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

Update the code above is now a working version.. for me anyway :)

Comment: It sounds like the problem isn't the height of the cell, but the height of the label. Is that correct? It would make sense because I don't see you set the height of the label anywhere.

Comment: hrmm... well I guess it might be.. I'll look into sorting out the label I think I have found a decent tutorial.. i will give it ago now...

Comment: I added the UILabel and have managed to get the size of the cell to approximately double.. but it happens to every cell in the tableview not just the cell with more text that I am wanting to dynamically enlarge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start over and follow this tutorial word for word and you'll be fine:
[Cocoa is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

It actually looks like you looked at this tutorial and only followed part of it. I still don't see you setting the frame of the label though.

Comment: yep thats the one I have been working with.. its got one issue in it now, which I don't know what to do with... **cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];** Excluding the autorelease if your using ARC initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: has been discontinued so I'm not sure what to do there...

Comment: Okay got it working.. seems to be messing with my cell selection and accessory views now but ill try and figure out that problem myself.. thanks for the help