# ios - UITableViewCells not extending to fit the text

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to make the cells inside my UITableView adapt to the length of the text in them.  If the text is too long, the cell grow a bit taller to fit it.

I am trying something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

cell.textLabel.text = [[name stringByAppendingString:@": "] 
                               stringByAppendingString:comment];
```

But what happens is that the cell just tries to fit the text into same vertical amount of space, and does not get any taller.

Would anyone know what I am doing incorrectly here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the cell height delegate.  Take a look here: [dynamic UITableViewCell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903369/dynamic-uitableviewcell-height) .

What you need to do is calculate the text height, and then set the cell's height to that.
Specifically this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *yourText = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 /*cell width*/, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize size = [yourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MIN(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height;
}
```

Comment: which part of that post? I looked it over and didn't see anything in the question that would do it.  Or did you mean the tutorial the answer pointed to?

Comment: You'll want to look at the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8903694/1535038.  The thing is you need to calculate the row height by passing the text and width, then return the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: thanks - but where did the CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH and the CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN come from? Is there a way to dynamically get those?

Comment: those are just constants for the cell width, you will most likely be able to replace that with 320

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I would like this to work on iPad and iPhone so is there a way to autmatically detect the device? Or is that done elsewhere?