# Resized UILabel in UITableViewCell display error

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, uilabel

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a UILabel with dynamic height, depending on it's content.

The resizing of the UILabel works perfectly, but the UILabel is not displaying It's content properly. The content is contained to 1 or 2 lines, even if it has space in It's frame.

**BUT** if I scroll the UITableView and the come back to those cells, everything is displayed perfectly.

I want the cells to be displayed correctly form the beginning without scrolling.

*Here are some screenshots from before and after scrolling:*
[image: UILabels (in blue) before scrolling]

[image: UILabel (in blue) after scrolling]

Here's the code I use for resizing the UILAbel:

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [titleText sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font
                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                lineBreakMode:titleLabel.lineBreakMode];
CGRect newFrame = titleLabel.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = 10;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
titleLabel.frame = newFrame;
accumulatedY += (expectedLabelSize.height + PADDING);

expectedLabelSize = [empresatext sizeWithFont:empresaLabel.font
                                 constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                     lineBreakMode:empresaLabel.lineBreakMode];
newFrame = empresaLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
newFrame.origin.y = accumulatedY;
empresaLabel.frame = newFrame;
accumulatedY += (expectedLabelSize.height + PADDING);
```

Comment: For starters you should be using `(CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context` as `sizeWithFont` has been deprecated. Also it wouldn't hurt to make sure your UILabel's line is set to 0.

Comment: Also make sure you're calculating the cell's height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you can resize the label but it won't fit if the cell doesn't know how tall the content is going to be.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the code you posted?

Comment: @JMarsh I'm calculating the cell height before everything. On view controllers init

Comment: @reecon The posted code is called in cellForRowAtIndexPath, initialising the cell.

Comment: Can you post your `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @JMarsh I use a prototype cell to calculate each future height of cells, I store the data in an array, and in "heightForRowAtIndexPath" I return this height data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "fixed" the problem by creating the UILabel programatically in "cellForRowAtIndexPath", as recommended in this thread: [UILabel in a UITableViewCell With Dynamic Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460093/uilabel-in-a-uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height)

Still intrigued why this isn't working with the UILabel created in the InterfaceBuilder :/